SpringBootTest and WebTestClient gives out 409 status conflict response when running more than one test
I wrote some integration tests with SpringBootTest and WebTestClient. But when I try to run them by clicking on run the test class and all of its test, it gives the status of 409 instead of when they are run one by one which gives 201 or 200 status code. If the problem is that all of them are run by one port, how can I configure it, so all of the test would pass together?
The code:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;

@Test
void happyPath_createIndex() {
    
    CreationInputDto input = new CreationInputDto();

    webTestClient
            .post()
            .uri("/create")
            .body(Mono.just(input), CreationInputDto.class)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isEqualTo(201);
}

@Test
void happyPath_adjustIndex_additionOperation() {
    
    happyPath_createIndex();
   
    AdjustmentInputDto input = new AdjustmentInputDto();

    webTestClient
            .post()
            .uri("/indexAdjustment")
            .body(Mono.just(input), AdjustmentInputDto.class)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isEqualTo(201);
}
}


Tests must be run independently.  Also, if data has already been created when calling happyPath_createIndex() for the first time, there is no need to call happyPath_createIndex() again below.
In the second test, you must write new webclient code by not calling happyPath_createIndex() or by writing Dto data that is different from the first test.
Try this:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void happyPath_createIndex() {
        CreationInputDto input = new CreationInputDto();
        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/create")
                .body(Mono.just(input), CreationInputDto.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(201);
    }

    @Test
    void happyPath_adjustIndex_additionOperation() {    
        AdjustmentInputDto adjustmentInput = new AdjustmentInputDto();
        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/indexAdjustment")
                .body(Mono.just(adjustmentInput), AdjustmentInputDto.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(201);
    }
}


The database is in memory H2 therefore by running the application every time the data should at first get saved and then edit can be done on them.
and my question is that how can I edit the code so when I run the test Class, it won't give conflict 409 status error.
